# Metaballs and particles

Tags: rendering, particles

I’m following a tutorial to create a paint splatter effect. I’ve got I’ve got a particle system and I’ve created a metaball to create a mesh from the particle system under parent in render. When I go to the particle system and try to make the metaball a mesh it just moves the particles on top of the metaball. It doesn’t create a mesh. Anyone know why?

Here is the tutorial I was watching: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Tz1U6A5vI)

Here is an example of whats happening when I try to parent the particle system to the metaball in the render section of the particle system. IT won't create a mesh. It just moves the particles on top of the metaball.

[image]

Comment: *"to the particle system and try to make the metaball a mesh"* what are you trying to do? If converting metaball to mesh then this isn't done in particle system settings, rather than via Alt+C shortcut in the viewport. You could specify what tutorial are you following and include exact moment of time where you have problems with some screenshots

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to parent the Particles to the Metaball.
You want the particles to become metaballs. you achieve this by changing the rendering object of the Particle system. In your screenshot the particles are set to "halo". Go to the Render-Section of your particle system and change that to "object" (yellow rectangle) and select your metaball. The particles themselves are now metaballs and can interact with each other.

[image]

[image]